# Finding probabilty of of getting heads of an unfair coin.

Tags: probability

In three flips of an unfair coin the probability of getting 3 heads is the same as that of getting exactly 2 tails. What is the ratio of the probability of flipping a tail to the probability of flipping a head. Express your answer as a common fraction in simplest radical form.

Answer: sqrt(3)/3

Can someone explain what's the general method for solving such unfair probability questions?

Answer (score 3):

Assume probability of tails is $p$.

The probability of three heads is $(1-p)^3$. Probability of two tails is $\binom{3}{2}p^2(1-p)$. Hence,
$$3p^2(1-p)=(1-p)^3$$

Therefore, $$\frac{p^2}{(1-p)^2}=\frac{1}{3}\Rightarrow \frac{p}{(1-p)}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Comment: Then the probability of tails is $p=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+1}=0.366$ and the probability of heads = $1-p=0.634$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $p$ denote the probability to flip a head, and $q$ denote the probability to flip a tail. Your first statement gives you an equation relating the two quantities (besides $p+q=1$), which you can then simplify to give you the desired answer: take note that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3}{3}.$$